# Failed when trying to create, get data from the database (pymongo, mongodb, docker-compose)

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, pymongo

I'm having the following error when I try to execute a get or post in my flask app.

> mongo:27017: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve (configured timeouts:
> socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout:
> 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id:
> 657c619ae1e4696f65e708c2, topology_type: Unknown, servers:
> [<ServerDescription ('mongo', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None,
> error=AutoReconnect('mongo:27017: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve
> (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS:
> 20000.0ms)')>]>

my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from pymongo import MongoClient
from loguru import logger
from bson.json_util import dumps

app = Flask(__name__)

MONGO_URI = "mongodb://admin:admin@mongo:27017/"

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    try:
        logger.info('Connecting to MongoDB')
        client = MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
        logger.info('Connected to MongoDB')
        db = client.test
        collection = db.test
        data = collection.find({})
        serialized_data = dumps(data)
        logger.info('Data retrieved successfully')
        return jsonify({"data": serialized_data}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": f"{str(e)}"}), 500

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def create_data():
    try:
        logger.info('Connecting to MongoDB')
        client = MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
        logger.info('Connected to MongoDB')
        db = client.test
        collection = db.test
        data = collection.insert_one({"name": "test"})
        logger.info('Data created successfully')
        return jsonify({"data": data}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": f"{str(e)}"}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - nginx

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/test
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db

volumes:
  mongodb_data:
```

The error saying that there is a connection error doesn't make much sense to me, because the logs that are being made show that the request passes through the connection line.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker containers are referenced by their service name; change your connection string to:

```
MONGO_URI = "mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/"
```

Note that creating the `MongoClient` object doesn't actually attempt a database connection, so you can't assume you're connected just because it doesn't fail at that point.

Answer (score 1):

From docker compose documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
> container for a service joins the default network and is both
> reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
> them at **a hostname identical to the container name**.
> ...

So in code, the uri for the database should be:

```
MONGO_URI = "mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/"
```

so `mongo` should be replaced by `mongodb`... Mostly an overside on your part.

What I also want to point out a security issue that is not commonly known about running docker compose on Linux. The issue is that `Docker` will not respect the `ufw` rules. Which means that the mongodb container running on port 27017 **will be reachable from the public internet**.

Read this for more:

https://blog.jarrousse.org/2023/03/18/how-to-use-ufw-firewall-with-docker-containers/
https://blog.viktorpetersson.com/2014/11/03/the-dangers-of-ufw-docker.html